# How to stop ORBIS CMS from automatically inserting <p> tags

Tags: html, css, xhtml, content-management-system

Driving me crazy, finally found a decent CMS that is open source and can be installed, it's called Orbis CMS. One problem, can't for the life of me think why someone creating such sweet software wouldn't know that not all editable regions need the `<p>` tags when stylesheets are used!

I'm using it on an already designed and developed page in xhtml and css so have all my styles etc sorted. But now that it inserts `<p>` everywhere you edit it stuffs up my `<h1> <h2>` etc tags.

Does anyone know a work-around/fix for this so it stops automatically putting in the `<p>` tags please? Changing some of the backend files or something?

Any help much appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I would urgently recommend to look for another CMS since Orbis CMS seems to be dead and not developed anymore (source: http://www.novo-ws.com/orbis-cms/). Aswell a search for "Orbis CMS Exploit" reveals several vulnerabilities which won't be fixed in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yep I've decided to give Orbis a miss after a little further research (prior to you writing this answer). Have decided to go with V-CMS, we love it. Highly customisable, integrated, installable, simple, fast, and looks GREAT! Thanks.