# Why won't my php lines work in my html file?

Tags: php, html, css, xhtml, content-management-system

Ok so I've recently installed to test Orbis CMS, and I love it, except two things - this being one of them.

Test page 'page.php' worked fine, great! Incorporated it into an existing html page and that's where I ran into the issue. Duhr, it won't run the php snippits.

Quick Google shed light that I needed to add a piece of code into the .htaccess file to allow the html file(s) to run the php code. Tried it, and nothing, didn't work, at all. Was going off this link (provided by Orbis) here: http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm

When I did it for all pages it started doing funky stuff and asking me to download/open pages when I clicked the links throughout the site, but not every link.. ?? When I did it for the single test page it didn't work full stop.

Anyone got any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: Shouldn't you rename your .html file to .php?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I already have a load of other websites linking to the pages I'm wanting to use so don't want to/can't change the extension of the file.

Comment: Please help with other related Q, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817668/how-to-stop-orbis-cms-from-automatically-inserting-p-tags

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just rename the .htm file to .php ? You can have normal HTML in PHP files aswell, just outside of the `<?php ?>`Tags.

.htaccess has to be allowed from your hoster, so that might be the reason why it didn't work.

EDIT: Then just replace the .htm File with a redirection to your .php file.
You can achieve this by `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/yourfile.php">`

Or if the .htaccess is run by the webserver you can do a redirect there:
`Redirect /youroldsite.htm yournewsite.php` (would be the better version)

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I already have a load of other websites linking to the pages I'm wanting to use so don't want to/can't change the extension of the file.

What do you mean .htaccess has to be "allowed" from the hoster? I have an .htaccess file there already so I assume it is "allowed"?

Is there a piece of code I can put into the htaccess file that works all the time and every time with no drawbacks/errors for running php code in html files?

Comment: I really don't want to change the extensions of all pages to .php, is there no way I can keep it html? The research I've done says that there is but each one I've tried won't seem to work.

Comment: Finally figured it out after more hours on Google.

AddType application/x-httpd-php4 .htm .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html

Comment: Please help with other related Q if possible, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817668/how-to-stop-orbis-cms-from-automatically-inserting-p-tags

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your .html to .php.
as you mentioned that .htaccess is not working check these thing it may help you
Is .htaccess enabled?

It's unusual, but possible that .htaccess is not enabled on your site. If you are hosting it yourself, it's easy enough to fix; open your httpd.conf in a text editor, and locate this  section

Your DocumentRoot may be different, of course

```
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "/var/www/htdocs">
#
```

locate the line that reads..

> AllowOverride None

and change it to..

> AllowOverride All

Restart Apache. Now .htaccess will work. You can also make this change inside a virtual host, which would normally be preferable.

If your site is hosted with someone else, check your control panel (Plesk. CPanel, etc.) to see if you can enable it there, and if not, contact your hosting admins. Perhaps they don't allow this. In which case, switch to a better web host.

and also check that rewrite_module is marked

Comment: All sorted mate thanks, just took hours of trial and error with all the different versions of code to parse the php in html in htaccess. If you can help with my other Q re; Orbis CMS please do :) stackoverflow.com/questions/9817668/how-to-stop-orbis-cms-from-automatically-inserting-p-tags

Answer (score 0):

Rename your Files to `.php` or change your server configuration to recognize `.htm` files as PHP files, too.

Example (httpd.conf):

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
</IfModule>
```

As an alternative you could setup `mod_rewrite` to route to your php file on specific URLs.

Comment: Sorry I'm a semi-noob at this sort of stuff. httpd.conf? Is that piece of coding above what I put into the htaccess file?

Comment: Finally figured it out after more hours on Google.

AddType application/x-httpd-php4 .htm .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html

Comment: Please help with other related Q if possible, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817668/how-to-stop-orbis-cms-from-automatically-inserting-p-tags

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `.html` to `.php`. You mentioned you need to keep the link equity from other sites to your `.html` pages. To get around this, simply add a `301 redirect` in your `.htaccess` file.

```
//301 Redirect
Redirect 301 oldfile.html newfile.php
```

Comment: Is this the only option? I'd prefer to get the php code to execute from within the html file if possible using "something" in the htaccess file. I've read numerous times that it works but for some reason the snippits I've chucked in there don't wanna play!

Comment: It's the easiest and quickest way to get it to work while keeping your link equity from the external sites. I'm sure you can brew up some other funky work-around, but why not just use this method? It works.

Comment: Lol sweet I'll keep that as a last resort but do you have any idea how to parse the php in the existing html files I've got? Cheers for the help.

Comment: It shouldn't be used as the last resort, it should be used as the answer. :) As the article you linked to points out, `.html` files are sent straight to the browser and an php script is ignored. That's just how it works. In the article they describe a way of messing with the `.htaccess` but it seems REALLY backwards.

Comment: Yea, fair enough. Although when designing and developing websites for friends and family (and clients) we say the designs are coded in HTML and CSS so having php extensions would look.. backwards. :)

Comment: Finally figured it out after more hours on Google.

AddType application/x-httpd-php4 .htm .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html

Comment: Please help with other related Q if possible, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817668/how-to-stop-orbis-cms-from-automatically-inserting-p-tags